# How to post data as json in codeigniter?

Tags: json, codeigniter

I have to post data as json object format in codeigniter. how can it make possible. 
My model function looks like:

```
public function signAction()
{
        $name=$this->input->post('name',TRUE);
        $dob=$this->input->post('dob',TRUE);
        $gender=$this->input->post('gender',TRUE);
        $country=$this->input->post('country',TRUE);
        $city=$this->input->post('city',TRUE);
        $mobile=$this->input->post('mobile',TRUE);
        $email=$this->input->post('email',TRUE);
        $password=$this->input->post('password',TRUE);

        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->or_where('mobile',$mobile);

        $query = $this->db->get('dr_signup');

        $value=$query->num_rows();
        if($value==0)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO dr_signup (name,dob,gender,country,city,mobile,email,password) 
                VALUES(".$this->db->escape($name).",".$this->db->escape($dob).",".$this->db->escape($gender).",".$this->db->escape($country).",
                       ".$this->db->escape($city).",".$this->db->escape($mobile).",".$this->db->escape($email).",".$this->db->escape($password).")";
                $value1=$this->db->query($sql);
                $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

                $details = array(
              'status'=>'success', 
              'message'=>'registered sucessfully',
              'id' => $insert_id ,
              'name' => $name,
              'dob'=>$dob,
              'gender'=>$gender,
              'country'=>$country,
              'city'=>$city,
              'mobile'=>$mobile,
              'email'=>$email,

              );

                echo  json_encode($details);
        }
        else
        {

            $detail = array(
            'status'=>'unsuccess', 
            'message'=>'already registered',

    );

    echo  json_encode($detail); 
        }

}
```

I have to post the data as json format. My json objects looks like:

```
{"name":"jon","dob":"1jan2015","gender":"male","country":"India","city":"Mumbai","mobile":"86064 70000","email":"sales@green.tech","password":"1234"}
```

I am new to this. How can it make possible. what all modification should I have to do in code. thanking in advance.

Comment: Post json to where? Your script is echoing a json encoded string already. What behaviour are you seeing that is wrong?

Comment: its for api development,   i have to use above json object instead of $name=$this->input->post('name',TRUE);

Comment: Once you get the json in any request parameter, just json decode the request variable and you will get an array/object of that json key-values

Comment: @Abin There is something fundamentally flawed here in your flow.  The part of your MVC structure that should be collecting your submission data is the Controller.  The Controller then passes the data to the Model which is where the querying is done.  The outcome of the query (affected rows) is then returned from the Model to the Controller.  The Controller echoes the correct json encoded string which your ajax call will read as the response value.

Answer (score 1):

say for example you get the json in `$this->input->post('json_string',true);` you can use the code like this..

```
$jsonstring = $this->input->post('json_string');
$json_data = json_decode($jsonstring,true); //remove true if you need object or keep it for array
```

The `$json_data` will give you the key value of the posted json string like `$json_data['name']` ...

Answer (score 0):

You try just like this

```
return json_encode($details); 

delete your code "echo  json_encode($details)"
```

I think it's working